# Limpar dados do formulário se houver o "refresh" da página?

Tags: php, html

Estou realizando um teste simples e gostaria de saber se há como limpar os dados do formulário se o usuário der um `refresh` no navegador.

```
<?php
$test1 = "";
$test2 = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{   $test1 = $_POST['test1'];
    $test2 = $_POST['test2'];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
    <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?php echo $test1;?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="test2" value="<?php echo $test2;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_sub" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Sempre que digito algo nos campos se eu der `refresh` no navegador os dados permanecem.
Gostaria de saber se é possível limpar esses campos ao clicar no refresh do navegador.

Comment: Ideia: Com onload de javascript setar values e innerHtml de elementos do formulário como vazio. Perceba que pra cada tipo de elemento precisará de um tratamento diferente.

Comment: Gostaria de ver com php, mas vlw a dica

Comment: Não sei bem como fazer em php, mas você pode ver se tem alguma função para limpar o cookie e o cash da página quando houver refresh.

Comment: Estou um pouco confuso. Os dados são preenchidos com dados do `POST`, então é basicamente você quem os está colocando lá. Então, quando o usuário atualizar a página, o navegador emite aquele alerta para reenviar os dados e estes aparecem novamente na página. Se entendi bem, o que você gostaria é que o refresh não reenviasse os dados do formulário ou que esse dados fossem ignorados na segunda vez que abrir a página, é isso?

Comment: Se minha suposição acima for verdadeira, o que você pode fazer é salvar uma flag na sessão do usuário na primeira vez que mostra o formulário. Na segunda vez, se a flag estiver presente, você não coloca os valores nos campos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere os cabeçalhos da requisição com `header` e diga ao *browser* para não salvar nada no *cache*:

```
<?php
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
$test1 = "";
$test2 = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $test1 = $_POST['test1'];
    $test2 = $_POST['test2'];
}?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
    <input type="text" name="test1" value="<?php echo $test1;?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="test2" value="<?php echo $test2;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_sub" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Fonte: [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers).